# How to access contents of some docker container in totally different docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have the following project structure

- `client folder`

  - `package.json`
  - `Dockerfile`
- `server folder`

  - `package.json`
  - `Dockerfile`

client needs a `npm run devserver` command and
server needs a `npm run develop` command. Both these commands simultaneously in 2 different terminals runs application in my local

The `client` folder uses some files which are present in `server` folder while running the `devserver` command. Now if I create separate dockerfiles in `client` and `server` folder. The `devserver` command wont be able to access files in `server` folder. And hence Im unable to start my application.

Is there any way I can access the files using dockerisation ? Maybe using docker-compose too not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `docker-compose.yaml` in the same folder of `server` and `client`, and specify `build context` as `.`, while afford an additional `dockerfile` option to meet your requirement, example as next:

**structure:**

```
root@pie:~/20221015# tree
.
├── client
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── server
    └── file_in_server
    └── Dockerfile
       
2 directories, 4 files
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  client:
    image: client_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: client/Dockerfile
```

**client Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine
COPY server/file_in_server /tmp
```

**execution:**

```
root@pie:~/20221015# docker-compose build --no-cache
Building client
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 9c6f07244728
Step 2/2 : COPY server/file_in_server /tmp
 ---> c5cc162bad75

Successfully built c5cc162bad75
Successfully tagged client_image:latest
root@pie:~/20221015# docker run --rm -it client_image ls /tmp/file_in_server
/tmp/file_in_server
```

You could see the `client dockerfile` successfully access the file in `server folder`, you can move to [build-definition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#build-definition) if you want to dig more.

Comment: I already have Dockerfiles present in both client and server folder, wont anything hamper it ?

Comment: I just omit the dockerfile in server folder as it's not used in the example, in fact, above solution not conflict with what you said. YOu could have another service named "server", and option dockerfiles pointed to your server's dockerfile.

Comment: No I meant conflict with the Dockerfile present already in client folder. I know server folder wont have any conflicts that's straightforward

Comment: If you mean you can't change any contents in `Dockerfile` especially for the relative path (server/file_in_server ), then no way to meet your requirement. This solution works just for the project which you have full control.

Comment: Sorry I got confused, your solution worked. Thanks :)